# Client side application help requested

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am testing an application.  In tableadapter configuration wizard,  On server side:
While choosing data source, I chose Microsoft SQL Server Database File.
This gave the connection string as:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

Is this correct?
Any way this works in my desired way.

Then in SQL Server Mgmt Express, I attached the database to the instance of my SQL Server Express (to MyhomeServer\SQLExpress"

Now I want to use the same application on Client side (off course databse is stored in Data Directory of my application in Server Side)  Now in tableadapter wizard, I choose Microsoft SQL Server Express.  Is that correct?
I have done all configurations for remote connection etc. and also done the firewall settings.  When I run this test on client side, it returns error:

Cannot open database "Database1.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'MYHOMESERVER\Kh. Furqn'.

Why does it go to Kh. Furqan while I am giving it SQLExpress, where the DB is attached.  My server is MyHomeServer\SQLExpress and connection is MyHomeServer\Kh. Furqan (Authentication is Windows Authentication, and no password for it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you chose integrated security the program will try to log onto SQL Server with the current logged on user's credentials - 'MYHOMESERVER\Kh. Furqn'.  So the first place I would check is make sure that you can log onto Sql Server Mgmt Studio (SSMS) Express with the windows logon option and logged into the server as Kh. Furqn.  Let me know if that works.

Wade